# Qlikview Substring and charindex equivalent to show values after the - character

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a field which has the values

```
field
good - examplea
good - exampleb
bad - examplep
ugly - examplet
ugly - exampley
```

I want to only show values after the `-` character.

My example output would be

```
field
examplea
exampleb
examplep
examplet
exampley
```

In SQL it would be simply

```
SUBSTRING('ugly - exampley',CHARINDEX('- ', 'ugly - exampley', 1)+2,250)
```

AND

```
SUBSTRING(field,CHARINDEX('- ', field, 1)+2,250)
```

What is the equivelant in Qlikview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use `mid` (with `index`) or `subfield` as follows:

**Mid & Index**

The equivalent of your statement would be:

```
mid(field, index(field,'- ', 1) + 2, 250)
```

Here, `mid` is the equivalent of `SUBSTRING` and `index` equivalent of `CHARINDEX`. However, in QlikView, `mid`'s third parameter (number of characters to return) is optional, so you could instead use

```
mid(field, index(field,'- ', 1) + 2)
```

which would return the remainder of the field value after the `-`.

**Subfield**

`Subfield` allows you to delimit your input string with another string and then return a specific delimited substring. In your case, the below would do the trick:

```
subfield(field, ' - ' , 2)
```

For example, for the string `good - examplea`, this breaks it down by looking for the delimiter `-`. This results in two strings, `good` and `examplea`. The last parameter, `2`, tells `subfield` to return `examplea` (rather than `good` which could be obtained by using `1` as the third parameter).

The good thing about subfield in your case is that you do not need to specify how many characters to return as subfield will return all characters to the end of the string.

Comment: `subfield(field, ' - ' , 2)` worked exactly as I wanted